# Is regex faster with many short pieces, or one large piece of text?

Tags: java, regex

I want to perform some regex replacements on the contents of a file (in Java).

Would it be more efficient to

1. Read one line of the file; regex replace it, add it to the `String file`, then read the next line; etc.

or

2. Read the entire file into `String file`; then regex replace that big string.

Was this researched, or does anybody know anything about this?

I'm guessing #2 will be more performant but will use more memory, but I'd like to make sure.

Comment: The second option is probably faster, because appending each line to some aggregate string actually creates a new string each time. Why not profile both schemes and see which one is faster?

Comment: This sounds more like a code review type of question...

Comment: I some cases, you can get different results. For example, if you'll use greedy quantifiers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second method would be way faster. But take my word, take my code!

```
File f = new File("somefile.txt"); // Get the file
List<String> lines_list = Files.readAllLines(f.toPath()); // read the file
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(); // the file is a list, lets create a string
lines_list.forEach(str::append); // add all of the lines to the string builder
final String fileString = str.toString(); // finally create a string from it.

long startTime = System.nanoTime();
lines_list.forEach(item -> item = item.replaceAll("\\^([0-9]+)", "<sup>$1</sup>"));
long endTime = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println("Iterating and replacing over list: "+(endTime - startTime));

startTime = System.nanoTime();
fileString.replaceAll("\\^([0-9]+)", "<sup>$1</sup>");
endTime = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println("Replacing the entire string: "+(endTime - startTime));
```

**Result**

```
Iterating and replacing over list: 156046464
Replacing the entire string: 1473488
```

Note that I'm using a list to replicate your first scenario. I think regardless, you'd have to deal with it as a list.

Note that the second approach is 100 times faster on a really large file. I used the Bible in text since it was free. It's 4.5 mb of simple text.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Good job & thanks for the great effort.